# Should I tell my partner my honest opinion about her career choice?

Tags: relationships, life-partner

My partner and I are working in close but distinct academic fields as researchers. It turns out that my career is reasonably successful, without being stellar, but her situation is more complicated. She simply does not produce enough research output, not because of a lack of skills (she is truly brilliant) but because she does not work enough. This is mostly due to the fact that she has mild mental health issues that make it difficult for her to concentrate on solitary tasks when she is distressed, which unfortunately happens quite often and tends to get worse over time.

She often asks me to tell her my "honest" opinion about her prospects. My honest opinion is that she should look for another job more compatible with her personality, and that opinion is shared by the vast majority of the people who know them. However, she gets infuriated when I only mention the idea that there are interesting activities to do outside academia. She accuses me of not believing in her potential, or even of intentionally crashing her self-confidence. She puts pressure on me to work together, which would not make sense at all given that our fields are distinct. This topic has become extremely sensitive between us.

I think she would just be happier if she admitted that this career is not a good fit for her, and if she switched to an activity with less pressure, more flexible hours, etc. That said, I am not sure that giving my honest opinion would help her, and it would probably jeopardize our relation. What should I say when she asks me this question?

Comment: Hi Oliv, unfortunately we can't make decisions for you about what to tell her. We might be able to help if you know you want to talk to her about how she feels about her career prospects, or how you feel about your future together, for instance. Do you have a particular goal for this conversation?

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you could benefit from the opinion of a third party.  Even one session with a counsellor or therapist (you mentioned mental health concerns) could help her to answer some questions objectively, without feeling like you're criticizing her.

I've been in her situation (still am), where career suffers in part due to mental health issues.  It's a lot easier to have these frank discussions in a support group, or with a therapist then it is with a partner.